# Porting a Windows compiled QT application to Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I created this simply application in Qt4 and would like to test it on RH Linux distro. The distro has both QtCore "Qt4" and Qt3 installed. I cannot add or delete any of these Qt versions, but would like to work with what's available.

I have an error compiling my windows based Qt program "Qt4" in Linux .
First question :
- How do I compile my compile in Linux without QT creator "only Qt libraries" are installed, what I did is get the .pro file from windows and typed qmake . , the errors are :

```
WARNING : Found potential symbol conflict of mainwindow.cpp (mainwwindow.cpp) in SOURCES
WARNING : Found potential symbol conflict of mainwindow.h (mainwwindow.cpp) in HEADERS
WARNING : Found potential symbol conflict of dialog.cpp (dialog.cpp) in SOURCES
WARNING : Found potential symbol conflict of dialog.h (dialog.h) in HEADERS
```

How can I modify qmake to specify the version of Qt
Thank you.

Below is my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TestTool
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    dialog.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    dialog.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    dialog.ui
```

The compilation error is  :

[image]

Comment: One doesn’t specify the Qt version in the .pro file, just call the right qmake. The warnings are quite weird, but also they’re are warnings, not errors, so check if things compile or not.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I added the error when compiled above. It just doesn't like QApplication, which means it uses qt3 not qt4

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Qt4 version of qmake explicitly:

```
/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake -o Makefile TestTool.pro
```

Comment: now the error is Mainwindow, it says it wasn't declared in this scope.....everything is included, don't have a clue as to why is complains about Mainwindow

Comment: @SamGomari Might be worth posting a second question about this next problem.